# How to close & open a modal like Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a modal like Bootstrap ...
I have wrote this codes :

```
<button type="button" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary">Open Modal</button>

<div class="modal fadeIn" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-header">
        Roj Framework <span class="close-btn">&times;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-content">
        Hi, This Roj Framework !
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        Continue ...
    </div>
</div>
```

But I have a problem in understanding how to close & open it. I put a data-target for button to match with Modal Box ID & I don't display the modal from the beginning ..., So I wrote this code but It doesn't work ...

```
$('.modal').css('display', 'none');

$('button').click(function(){
    var boxID = $(this).data('target');
    var modalBox = $('.modal');
    var modalBoxAttr = modalBox.attr('id');
    if('boxID' == 'modalBoxAttr') {
        modalBox.css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a few mistakes with your code.

**Mistake 1:**

Here:

`if('boxID' == 'modalBoxAttr')`

You are currently checking the `strings` and not the `objects`. What you have written is the following:

If the string "boxId" is equal to the string "modalBoxAttr" do something. And both strings are not the same, so you get a `false` result.

**Mistake 2:**

You are complicating the code too much.

You can just simplify it like this.

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    var boxID = $(this).data('target');
    var boxObject = $(boxID);

    if(boxObject.length) {
        boxObject.toggle();
    }
});
```

```css
.modal { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary">Open Modal</button>

<div class="modal fadeIn" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-header">
        Roj Framework <span class="close-btn">&times;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-content">
        Hi, This Roj Framework !
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        Continue ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Use more often `console.log()` to debug your code and check if you are actually entering a specific section and if your logic is correct.

Comment: Thanks drip ... I have a question, I didn't get why my Mistake 1 is incorrect ... Because I have checked two strings & They have a Same Value ...

Comment: @AliBahaari You have to perform the check on the `objects`. So it should be written like this: `if(boxID == modalBoxAttr)` without the parenthesis. If you wrap the objects in parenthesis they become a string instead.

Comment: Thanks, I have another question ..., What does 'boxObject.length' mean ?

Comment: @AliBahaari if the object is present it will return `1` which is a `truthy` value. If the object is not present it will return `0` which is a `falsy` value. So with that `if` I'm checking if the object is present in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Try following approach.

> Remove data-target="#myModal" from button

```
  <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary">Open Modal</button>
```

Button click:

```
$('button').click(function(){
 $("#myModal").modal('show');
}});
```

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the question.

Comment: @prabhakaran S Thanks for your response My Friend, But I think you are not sure what I said ...